# Success function in ajax does not work

Tags: ajax, increment

The variable total should be incremented (total++) when the ajax function is successful and the name is inserted in the database.
But when the record is inserted, the total++ does not work, the alert("name successfully inserted" does not show and every time I insert a new name, the total is 1 instead of incrementing.
I hope you can help me.

HtML

```
<form  action="" method="post">
          <div class="form-item">
            <input id="name" type="text"  name="name">
          </div>
    </form>
```

This is the jquery/ajax script

```
 <script>    
        $(document).ready(function(){ 
             var total = 1;                
            $('#name').keydown(function(e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                      var name= $("#name").val();                        
                       var dataString = 'idUser='+ idUser
                        + '&total=' + total
                        + '&name=' + name

                      $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: 'insertName.php',
                        data: dataString,
                         success: function() { 
                           alert("name successfully inserted") 
                           total++;
                         }   
                      }); 
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
This is the insertName.php file
<?php

if(isset($_POST['idUser'])) $idUser= ($_POST['idUser']); 
if(isset($_POST['total'])) $total=($_POST['total']);
if(isset($_POST['name'])) $name= utf8_decode($_POST['name']);

$name=mysql_escape_string($name);


$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}


// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO names(idUser, date, total, name)
VALUES ('$idUser', CURDATE(), '$total', '$nom')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {

} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: so how does it not work? Are you positive the success callback is actually called? Use your console, add console statements, add an error handler to the Ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

`tota++;`

You're missing an 'l' at the end there.

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because the `total` variable is not global in nature as it is declared inside DOM ready.

To make it work declare the `total` outside DOM ready.

```
 var total; 
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
     total = 1;
     //your operation goes here.
     success: function() { 
              alert("name successfully inserted") 
              total++;
     }   
 });
```